# HBase convertScanToString method not accepting scan.write

Tags: hbase

I am trying to add `TableInputFormat.SCAN` into config object. Therefore, I have to convert scan object to String. However, in the code below: `scan.write(dos)` shows compile time exception i.e. it is not finding `write()`. I am importing package `import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;` and having respective JAR version: *hbase-client-1.1.2.2.6.5.1000-24.jar*

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setTimeRange(0L, 10L);                                
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
scan.write(dos); <---- compile time exception, no write() method exist!
```

Appreciate any help provided.

Comment: You wanted scan object to be written in "ByteArrayOutputStream out" ?

Answer (score 0):

Following code resolved the issue of converting scan object to string:

```
private static String convertScanToString(Scan scan) {
try {
ClientProtos.Scan proto = ProtobufUtil.toScan(scan);            
return Base64.encodeBytes(proto.toByteArray());
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return "";
}}
```

Import: import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos;